# Asp.Net Core No Service for Type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I am having problems to access `RoleManager` and `UserManager` inside my `Startup.cs` class. This is the code I use to register `Identity`:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(cfg =>
{
    cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    cfg.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<CarinioContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>();
```

User is my custom class that inherits from `IdentityUser` and expands it by some additional properties.

I have a function inside the `startup.cs` class to create roles and a user. I know this is not great for seeding and I will change it in the future but I need to get it working this way first. This is my code:

```
private async Task CreateRoles()
{
    //adding custom roles
    var UserManager = _serviceProvicer.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
    var RoleManager = _serviceProvicer.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Client", "Driver" };
    IdentityResult roleResult;

    foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
    {
        //creating the roles and seeding them to the database
        var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
        if (!roleExist)
        {
            roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
        }
    }

    //creating a super user who could maintain the web app
    var poweruser = new User
    {
        UserName = _configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserName"],
        Email = _configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"],
        PhoneNumber = _configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["PhoneNumer"],
    };

    string UserPassword = _configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserPassword"];
    var _user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(_configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"]);

    if (_user == null)
    {
        var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(poweruser, UserPassword);
        if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
        {
            //here we tie the new user to the "Admin" role
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "Admin");
        }
    }
}
```

The program always crashes saying :

```
"One or more errors occurred. (No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.)"
```

And the same goes for the `UserManager`:

```
"One or more errors occurred. (No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.)"
```

My guess is that I am not accessing the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` the right way. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

dotnet core has awesome feature for seeding role or user in first time
In entityconfiguration part of efcore you can use blow class to creating your default roles:

```
public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
       builder.HasData(new Role() {Id=1, Name = "Manager", NormalizedName = "MANAGER",Title="manager" }, new Role() {Id=2, Name = "Student", NormalizedName = "STUDENT",Title="student" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modify your code :

```
var UserManager = _serviceProvicer.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

to :

```
var UserManager = _serviceProvicer.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
```

If you create custom class that inherits from `IdentityUser` , you need to register the new `User` in `ConfigureServices` :

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>
```

In `CarinioContext` something like :

```
public class CarinioContext: IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole, string>
```

And in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`:

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
```